# Cant install RabbitMQ on Fedora fc12

Tags: rabbitmq, fedora12

I was following the steps from https://tecadmin.net/install-rabbitmq-on-centos/

The errors I get are:
1.required erlang version >=R16B03, but the one I installed on my fc12 is R13 which somehow refuses to upgrade and says it is the latest version and there is nothing to upgrade.

Check this image:
[rpm package successfully downloaded](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nPdMK.png)

But, when I try to install the package it says,

```
No package rabbitmq-server-3.6.9-1.e16.noarch.rpm available.
```

So, how do I install the required version of erlang?

Also,why does it say that the package is unavailable even though it was successfully downloaded?

Thank You for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both that Erlang version and RabbitMQ version are old and out of support. You should read the RabbitMQ team's instructions ([link](https://www.rabbitmq.com/install-rpm.html)) on how to install on RPM-based distributions.

Comment: Yes, I found the solution .For those with the same problem, just go the release page of rabbitmq and get the rpm file that supports your version of erlang and manually install it after downloading the package.For me, I have an erlang version 13B04 for which the rabbitmq rpm version would be rabbitmq-server-3.5.8-1